# SQL: SELECT id, MAX(y.DateCreated) FROM x LEFT JOIN y in Linq?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I can't seem to rewrite this SQL into EF Linq:

```sql
SELECT      Conversation.Id
FROM        Conversation LEFT JOIN Message
                ON  Conversation.Id = Message.ConversationId
GROUP BY    Conversation.Id
ORDER BY    MAX(Message.DateCreated) DESC
```

I would think something like this would work:

```cs
 _dbContext.Conversation
           .OrderByDescending(c => c.Messages.DefaultIfEmpty().Max(m => m.DateCreated))
           .Select(cm => cm.Id);
```

But this gives me the error `System.InvalidOperationException : Sequence contains no elements.`

Also this:

```cs
_dbContext.Conversation
          .Select(c => new {c.Id, MaxDate = c.Messages.DefaultIfEmpty().Max(m => m.DateCreated)})
          .OrderByDescending(c => c.MaxDate)
          .Select(cm => cm.Id);
```

But that gives me `System.ArgumentException : At least one object must implement IComparable.`.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) would help you?

Comment: I think, you may get some ideas from this post. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data

Comment: @NetMage I think that converges with Guaravsa 's query.  I am close but haven't figured out why my DefaultIfEmpty isn't working with Max and an empty set of subrecords.

Comment: What is the datatype of `Messages`? What would the "default" be for that? What is the result of calling `Max` on that? (Alternatively, what is the type of `MaxDate`?)

Comment: Also, what does `MAX` evaluate to when there are no matching `Message` rows and what order does that end up in?

Comment: Messages is an `ICollection<Message>` on `Conversation`...

Comment: It currently looks like `_dbContext.Conversation
                .GroupJoin(_dbContext.Message, c => c.Id, m => m.ConversationId, (c, m) =>
                    new { c, m })

                .SelectMany(cm => cm.m.DefaultIfEmpty(new Message { DateCreated = DateTime.MaxValue }), (cm, m) => new { cm.c, m })
                .GroupBy(cm1 => new { cm1.c.Id }, cm1 => cm1.m)
                .Select(cm => new { cm.Key.Id, MaxDateCreated = cm.Max(x => x.DateCreated) })
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.MaxDateCreated).Select(x => x.Id)`

Comment: I'm not sure what that means? I was trying to find out what happens in SQL when `MAX` has no matching rows, but I think my answer means it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will generate the SQL you are looking for (plus or minus a nested sub-query):

```
var ans = from c in Conversation
          join m in Message on c.Id equals m.ConversationId into mj
          from m in mj.DefaultIfEmpty()
          group m by c.Id into mg
          orderby mg.Max(m => m.DateCreated) descending
          select mg.Key;
```

However, in LINQ you can use group join instead of regular join. This should also do what you want, but uses a sub-select in SQL, so I am not sure which is more efficient on the server. The common wisdom seems to be join was better, but following by group by may make it moot, as may a modern enough optimizer. Another post I found said the sub-query (CIS) was much more efficient, so this may be better.

```
var ans2 = from c in Conversation
           join m in Message on c.Id equals m.ConversationId into mj
           orderby mj.Max(m => m.DateCreated) descending
           select c.Id;
```

Comment: Thanks, the first version seems to work.  I added a parameter to `DefaultIfEmpty` so that null values would come out on top, which LINQ isn't able to translate into EF, but I can deal with that.  (The second doesn't handle the empty set of messages)

Comment: I had arrived at a near-equivalent query which wasn't working---the only difference between mine and yours was that projection was happening differently in different places.  I guess I need to keep those as simple as possible at each step of the query.

Comment: @mikebridge The second worked correctly in LINQ to SQL on my MS SQL Server database, but EF isn't always the same.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
from r in Conversation
              join ru in Message
              on r.Id equals ru.ConversationId into ps
              from ru in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
              group ru by new { ru.ConversationId, ru.DateCreated } into rug
              select new {
                  id = ru.ConversationId,
                  datecreated = rug.Max(ru => ru.datecreated)
              }).OrderByDescending(x => x.datecreated);
```

This maynot compile as I dont have the code to test this with (like a fiddle)

Comment: You can just do `form ru in r.Messages.DefaultIfEmpty()` instead.

Comment: @Gauravsa This is pretty close, thanks!  I haven't successfully gotten DefaultIfEmpty to work against a missing set of subrecords, though---still working on that.

Answer (score 1):

You're close though, just drop `DefaultIfEmpty`

```
_dbContext.Conversation.Select(con => new 
    {
        con.Id,
        MaxDateCreated = (DateTime?) con.Messages.Max(msg => msg.DateCreated)
    })
.OrderByDescending(con => con.MaxDateCreated)
.ToArray()
```

Here is what's going to get generated

```
SELECT 
[Project2].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project2].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Project2].[C2] AS [C2]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    1 AS [C1], 
     CAST( [Project1].[C1] AS datetime2) AS [C2]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        (SELECT 
            MAX([Extent2].[DateCreated]) AS [A1]
            FROM [dbo].[Message] AS [Extent2]
            WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[ConversationId]) AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[Conversation] AS [Extent1]
    )  AS [Project1]
)  AS [Project2]
ORDER BY [Project2].[C2] DESC
```

Comment: I think this misses out on the left-join.  This would work if I switched it to `MaxDateCreated = con.Messages.Select(x => x.DateCreated).DefaultIfEmpty(DateTime.MaxValue).Max()`.  In either case, though, `Max()` is getting evaluated locally rather than in the DB.

Comment: No it does not. I edited the post with the generated query, which is equivalent to the left-join result that you wanted. You don't need `DefaultIfEmpty` since EF will do that for you already.

Comment: I get a `System.InvalidOperationException : Sequence contains no elements.` error on `Max()` when it hits an empty set of `.Messages`.